# How can I optimize this getter performance issue?

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, ngrx

In an angular component using NgRX store I have this bit of template

```
<p>{{ someObservable | async | assertNotNull }}</p>
```

which comes from the following getter

```
get someObservable(): Observable<number> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(state => state.myObservableValue));
}
```

The problem is that it returns a new Observable at each change detection cycle and the async pipe unsubscribes/subscribes every time.

How can I improve this in an elegant and performance-compliant way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a normal readonly property

```js
public readonly someObservable: Observable<number> = this.store.pipe(select(state => state.myObservableValue));
```

Comment: Thank you now could you give me some more explanations on how does readonly props save performances regarding change detection cycles please ?

Comment: its value has been assigned only once during the object initialization, and with every access there's no getter call.

Comment: But will its value be updated whenever state value changes ?

Comment: yes, that's what `select` does. every time `this.store` emits something it will return the related shape of `state.myObservableValue`. You should try it to see how it works.